# Photo Retrieval Issues

Tags: graph, photo

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/userID/
And I get the correct response

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/usersuserid/photo/$value/
And I get user resource can't be discovered

I have added Directory.Read.All, Group.Read.All, User.Read, User.ReadBasic.All permissions to the application.

Am I missing something?  thx

Comment: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/userid/photo/$value/.  if i put my userid in i get a photo back.

Comment: if i add the email instead of the userid i get error authenticating